# ASP.NET 4 web.config transformation MSBUILD

Tags: web-config, asp.net-4.0, transformation, msbuild-task

I want to use the newly introduced web.config transformation options in VS2010. But I'm not using the Deploy option of VS2010, i'm using Web Deployment Projects with MSBUILD tasks.

Can I apply the transformation with an MSBUILD task?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MSBuild Script and VS2010 publish apply Web.config Transform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905151/msbuild-script-and-vs2010-publish-apply-web-config-transform)