# Run web.config transformation from command-line

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, msbuild

Good day!

I want to have ability to build ASP.NET MVC 2 project using VS2010 Publish dialog *and* from command-line.

For command-line I get the following to work:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe .\SolutionFolder\MyProject.csproj /p:Configuration=Release;DeployOnBuild=True;PackageAsSingleFile=False;outdir=c:\_OutputFolder\
```

The only problem I have that Web.config transformation are not applied (but added to WebDeploy package). I don't use WebDeploy. Is there any way to apply Web.config transformations?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MSBuild Script and VS2010 publish apply Web.config Transform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905151/msbuild-script-and-vs2010-publish-apply-web-config-transform)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can also try using the XDT Transformation Tool:

http://ctt.codeplex.com was moved to Github
https://github.com/greenfinch/ctt

I'm using this instead of messing with obscure msbuild targets.

Comment: Seems to be the best solution so far.

Comment: All of the documentation links are dead on this page now.

Answer (score 20):

Here is another approach, which uses msbuild to transform Web.config file:

http://sedodream.com/2010/04/26/ConfigTransformationsOutsideOfWebAppBuilds.aspx

In my tests the results were better. Basically, you create a project file to perform only a TransformXML task:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Demo" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml"
         AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll"/>

<Target Name="Demo">
    <TransformXml Source="app.config"
                  Transform="Transform.xml"
                  Destination="app.prod.config"/>
</Target>
</Project>
```

Save the project file and then apply the transformation, running the following command:

> msbuild trans.proj /t:Demo

Where **trans.proj** is the name of the project file and **Demo** is the name of task target.

Comment: This is an awesomely simple way to do this.  Replace `v10.0` with `v15.0` for Visual Studio 2017 to allow it to find the dll.

Comment: This works wonders. It even output warnings for keys that couldn't be transformed (e.g. keys with a "replace" transform in the transform file that weren't found in the file the transform is being applied to).

Comment: I can't get this work with Visual studio 2017 Community. I got this error: error MSB4062: The "TransformXml" task
could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Pub
lishing.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's worth to mention that you can also use with **PowerShell** the DLL that Visual Studio is using: `Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.dll`

PowerShell script, see: [Web.Config transforms outside of Microsoft MSBuild?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989737/web-config-transforms-outside-of-microsoft-msbuild)

To load the DLL instead of copying around, I do like this (so you see where to find this DLL, at least in my scenario at work we had to look-up these locations):

```
if (Test-Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.dll") {
    Add-Type -LiteralPath "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.dll"
} elseif (Test-Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.dll") {
    Add-Type -LiteralPath "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.dll"
} else {
    throw [System.IO.FileNotFoundException] "Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.dll not found."
}
```