# How to pass Command line argument to specflow test scenario

Tags: c#, command-line, specflow

I am trying to run my specflow test scenarios from command line and im wondering is it possible to pass any command line argument to my specflow scenario.

My scenario is like this:
    Scenario: Test Connection to my server
    Given Get server ipaddress
    When  I press connect
    Then  I should get connected

When i say "Get server ipaddress" then i am able to read command line argument. Is it possible??

Or anyone have any other solution or suggestion. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'd use the .net configuration system - put your server connection strings into the connectionstrings settings element (or if you have a religious objection to putting something non-database there, use appsettings) and read from your settings.  if you want to have different config files for different environments, use config transformations to create different configuration.  this will allow you to keep everything in the project and not have to depend on setting up environment variables for your application.  you can script creating transformed config files using the [command line transform execution tool](https://nuget.org/packages/WebConfigTransformRunner/).

i have done something similar to use config files with my specs hitting web pages to switch which driver i'm using for selenium webdriver and wound up just copying my specs assemblies multiple times with different config files so i can run from different directories to execute different browsers.  you could do something similar for desire to connect to different machines or just spit out different config files and swap those in and out of your execution directory (or just manually change config when you want to execute something different).

you should also get the obligatory "that scenario isn't really a bdd scenario and should be more a story about a business capability than the technical scenario you have there to use bdd tools like specflow the way they were intended" statement for this to be a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older post, but the way I am solving this is by leveraging nunit parameters (I am running SpecFlow with nUnit).  So, for example, I am passing in a parameter of `environment` (i.e. Dev, QA, Prod) and based on that value, the relevant test data file that contains environment specific values (i.e. API base URL) will change.  I am using different "test data" files that will contain environment-specific values based on that environment parameter that is passed in.

The code used to read in that parameter looks like this:

```
// get the correct URL and user creds based on the environment passed in
var environment = TestContext.Parameters.Get("environment");
var dataFile = $"{environment}-test-data.json";
```

As you can see, that environment parameter that was passed, is being retrieved by nUnit TestContext object.  And the value of that parameter is then used to retrieve the correct test data file above.

And the "<environment>-test-data.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "baseUrl": "https://dev-some-endpoint.net",
}
```

Finally, I am reading in values from the test data file like this:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).AddJsonFile(dataFile).Build();
var url = config.GetSection("baseUrl").Value;
```

Answer (score -1):

Specflow doesn't provide any mechanism to do this.

While I can see why you might think you want to do this, be careful to consider what is going to happen by linking your tests to an external dependency such as the service that you are going to connect to. While you will have built yourself a means of automating a set of tests, there will be many reasons why they fail. For example, servers not running, configuration not being vaild or even differences in version of client and server.

Personally in instances where I have wanted to test the full regression of interprocess communication I have hosted both the client and the server in my tests so that I can more easily control that they start and stop both parts. Even then these tests are very flaky compared with tests that cut out the communication stack, and do occasionally fail.

*But if you really do want to go ahead*

All running code inherits a copy of the environment variables that were in existance at the time the command started. You can set them with `set Name=value` before starting SpecFlow and get at them with `Environment.GetVariable(variableName)` inside your Given method.

Comment: i really appreciate for your advice. Im very new with this specflow tool so im just trying to do thinks with that.