# Executing msbuild task from powershell

Tags: msbuild, powershell-2.0

I am following this blog: http://sedodream.com/2010/04/26/ConfigTransformationsOutsideOfWebAppBuilds.aspx

it's linked in this question as answer: [Web.Config transforms outside of Microsoft MSBuild?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989737/web-config-transforms-outside-of-microsoft-msbuild)

Every step works as described but I want to call the transformation from a powershell script.
I want to do this command in powershell `msbuild trans.proj /t:Demo`
I found some forums saying that I should use `invoke-expression`

When I try I get this error

Powershell:

```
Invoke-Expression $msbuild transformCommand.proj /t:Demo
```

Result

```
Invoke-Expression : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Command' because it is null.
At D:/Somewhere
+ Invoke-Expression <<<<  $msbuild transformCommand.proj /t:Demo
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpre
   ssionCommand
```

I also tried:

```
Invoke-Expression msbuild transformCommand.proj /t:Demo
```

With result

```
 D:\Somewhere
Invoke-Expression : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'transformCommand.proj'.
At D:\Redgate\Communited.Timeblockr.Api\PreDeploy1.ps1:14 char:18
+ Invoke-Expression <<<<  msbuild transformCommand.proj /t:Demo
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand
```

Small note: this is my first time using powershell.

TransformCommand.proj

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Demo" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml"
             AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll"/>
    <Target Name="Demo">
        <TransformXml Source="Web.Test.config"
                      Transform="transform.xml"
                      Destination="Web.acceptatie.config"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

My questions are:
Is this possible? And how is it possible?

Edit:

```
$a = "Path\transformCommand.proj /t:Demo"
#Invoke-Expression $msbuild $a

Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe" -ArgumentList $a | Write-Host
```

This actually does everything I need..

Still if there are ways to do this more "indepent" or better ways, please post it.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure you define the PowerShell variable $msbuild as below before calling Invoke-Expression $msbuild

```
$msbuild = "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe"
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing the following to build a solution with multiple parameters

```
&$msbuildExe ('solution.sln','/verbosity:q','/p:configuration=Release','/t:Clean,Build')
if (!$?) {
    echo "!!! ABORTING !!!";pause;exit    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add all the differences from the `%PATH%` from the `Developer Command Prompt for VS...` to powershell then you can run `msbuild` in powershell just like you would in the command prompt and everything seems to work. You also need to copy the variable `%VCInstallDir%`.

Here is a powershell function that I wrote to get the differences.

```
function Find-Path-Differences {
    $defaultPath = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine") + ";" + [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","User")
    $env:path.split(';') | Sort-Object -Unique | Where-Object { $defaultPath.split(';') -notcontains $_ }  | Foreach-Object { "`$env:path += `";$_`"`r" } | echo
    echo "function VCInstallDir {return `"$VCInstallDir`"}`r"
}
```

If you open powershell and type `echo $profile` that will give you a filepath. Create or open the file then paste the function into it and the function will be available when powershell starts. Then in the `Developer Command Prompt ...` run this command:

```
powershell Find-Path-Differences
```

And out will pop a bunch of lines like these:

```
$env:path += ";C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\\MSBuild\15.0\bin"
...
$env:path += ";C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319"
```

Copy and paste those lines into the file from `echo $profile` then open a new powershell window and you can now use `msbuild` in powershell.