# Task to modify App.config in TeamCity

Tags: .net, svn, msbuild, continuous-integration, teamcity

TeamCity CI has a variable `%system.build.number%` which will be incremented in the format `1.0.%build.counter%.0`. This will generate assemblies with different version number each time. I want to add this new version number in my app.config file. Whats the easiest way to do this. I have 100 projects which have app.config and mostly all use the same assemblies. Can I have a common app.config file which I can link and modify it. Well, please provide a example of how to modify the `newVersion` field in the binding redirect to the current build number provided by teamcity using a XmlTransform.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>     
  <runtime>
    <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="1" />
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">     
    <assemblyIdentity name="MyApp.Data.Model" publicKeyToken="866d4a0fa0594321" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.1.0" newVersion="1.0.2.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use xdt transformations.
Here is a snippet of powershell function, [Web.Config transforms outside of Microsoft MSBuild?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989737/web-config-transforms-outside-of-microsoft-msbuild)

You then create meta runner (more help http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Working+with+Meta-Runner) for transforming configs with XDT and use it in a build step. That's it :)

You could also create msbuild task and invoke msbuild instead of powershell function.