# How do I display an entire XML tree in Powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell, printing, tree, display

I am looking for a way to iterate through an XML API-based response and display the entire XML tree in the following format:

```
node\node = VALUE
node\node\node = VALUE
node\node\node2 = VALUE
```

I have a script that works for some XML output but fails on others:

```
    function Get-XMLTree($xml) {
        $nodesWithText = $xml.SelectNodes("//*[text()]")
    
        foreach($node in $nodesWithText) {
            #Start with end of path (element-name of the node with text-value)
            $path = $node.LocalName
            
            #Get parentnode
            $parentnode = $node.ParentNode
    
            #Loop until document-node (parent of root-node)
            while($parentnode.LocalName -ne '#document') {
    
                #If sibling with same LocalName (element-name) exists
                if(@($parentnode.ParentNode.ChildNodes | Where-Object { $_.LocalName -eq $parentnode.LocalName }).Count -gt 1){
                    #Add text-value to path
                    $path = "{0}\$path" -f ($parentnode.'#text').Trim()
                }
    
                #Add LocalName (element-name) for parent to path
                $path = "$($parentnode.LocalName)\$path"
    
                #Go to next parent node
                $parentnode = $parentnode.ParentNode
            }
    
            #Output "path = text-value"
            "$path = $(($node.'#text').Trim())"
        }
    }
```

For some XML responses, this works without a hitch. For others, I receive errors similar to the below:

```
InvalidOperation: /script1.ps1:51:17
Line |
  51 |                  $path = "{0}\$path" -f ($parentnode.'#text').Trim()
     | You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you post a minimal xml document that gives you the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! Here is the final function

```
function Get-XMLTree($xml) {
    $nodesWithText = $xml.SelectNodes("//*[text()]")
    foreach($node in $nodesWithText)
    {    
        #Start with end of path (element-name of the node with text-value)
        $path = $node.LocalName

        #Get parentnode
        $parentnode = $node.ParentNode

        #Loop until document-node (parent of root-node)
        while($parentnode.LocalName -ne '#document')
        {
            #If sibling with same LocalName (element-name) exists
            if(@($parentnode.ParentNode.ChildNodes | Where-Object { $_.LocalName -eq $parentnode.LocalName }).Count -gt 1)
            {
                #Add text-value to path
                if($parentnode.'#text')
                {
                    $path = "{0}\$path" -f ($parentnode.'#text').Trim()
                }
            }

            #Add LocalName (element-name) for parent to path
            $path = "$($parentnode.LocalName)\$path"

            #Go to next parent node
            $parentnode = $parentnode.ParentNode
        }

        #Output "path = text-value"
        "$path = $(($node.'#text').Trim())"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

XSLT seems like the tool for this job to extract information from an xml format.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16798553/555142) gives the gist of how to apply xslt in powershell.
Or, using one of many other [XSLT tools ...](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/logging_xml#xslt).

As @mclayton asked - if you can provide the original xml, someone might be able to give you a quick xslt to extract the information you are looking for.