# How to use MSBuild to do web.config without building the projects?

Tags: msbuild

I just need the transformed web.config, is there any way just use MSBuild to get it transformed **without** compiling the project?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [MSBuild Script and VS2010 publish apply Web.config Transform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905151/msbuild-script-and-vs2010-publish-apply-web-config-transform)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [XmlPreprocess tool](http://xmlpreprocess.codeplex.com/) for config files manipulation. It is using one mapping file for multiple environments. You can edit mapping file by Excel. It is very easy to use.